# Bounds of a solid region triple integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to find the integral of
(e^y)dV, where D is the solid region bounded by planes y=1, z=0, y=x, y=-x, and z=y.

I set the integral up as (e^y)dzdydz

but I am unsure how to determine the bounds of y and x. I am confused how to determine these because y=x, y=-x would give the same bounds for y/x and there is only 1 other bound for y.

Here is my initial attempt:
I integrate (e^y)dzdydx
where the bounds of z are [0,y]
the bounds of y are [-x,x] but I am unsure where to go from there... I think I am messing up my x/y bounds of integration

Could someone please give me a point in the correct direction?

Comment: I think your approach looks OK, but there are two sets of limits on $y$ depending on whether $x>0$ or $x<0$, necessitating two separate integrals. You can fix this by making $y$ the outer variable and $x$ the middle variable. Did you get $4-10e^{-1}$?

Comment: So If I made it dzdxdy, the x bounds would be -y to y? How would I determine the y bounds since there are so many options?

Comment: OK, I'll try writing up an answer with a figure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The projection into the $xy$-planes shows the outline formed by the planes $y=1$, $y=x$, and $y=-x$.

[image: figure 1]

You can see that if $x$ is the outer variable, then for $x\le0$, $-x\le y\le1$, whereas when $x\ge0$, $x\le y\le1$. You can determine that by drawing a vertical line (a curve of constant x) through the figure. That means we would have to break up the integral into $2$ pieces. But with $y$ the outer variable, drawing a horizontal line (a curve of constant y) through the figure reveals that the limits on $x$ should be $-y\le x\le y$. In $3$-d view,
[image: figure 2]

If we draw a vertical line (a curve of constant $x$ and $y$) through the figure, it enters at the $z=0$ plane and exits at the $z=y$ plane, so the limits on $z$ are $0\le z\le y$. Putting this all together into a triple integral,
$$\begin{align}\int\int\int e^{y}d^3V&=\int_0^1\int_{-y}^y\int_0^ye^y\,dz\,dx\,dy\\
&=\int_0^12y^2e^y\,dy\\
&=\left.(2y^2-4y+4)e^y\right|_0^1\\
&=2e-4\end{align}$$
I got a different answer in my comment because I misread the integrand as $e^{-y}$. The integral was easy to do via [tabular integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Tabular_integration_by_parts), my tableau is as follows
$$\begin{array}{lrl}2y^2&+&e^y\\4y&-&e^y\\4&+&e^y\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank You! Very detailed figures/explanation. I appreciate it